# On boot my machine is just showing black screen and a terminal,how can I set it back to normal?

Tags: boot-repair

On boot my machine is just showing black screen and a terminal,how can I set it back to normal?

[image]

Comment: If this is Ubuntu Server that you've installed, that *is* normal 

Comment: I was initially using the normal ubuntu desktop. but three days ago ,on booting it shows that black screen. How can I get back to normal ubuntu?

Comment: Have you uninstalled the desktop? Check your logs in `/var/log/apt` to see if you (accidentally) removed packages that were required for the desktop 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.